# Build an unsigned apk for Amazon and a signed apk for Google

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have two build types (*debug* and *release*) and two product flavors (*google* and *amazon*) and I need to be able to specify all variants to be signed with *signingConfigs.release* except the *amazonRelease* variant which needs to be signed with *signingConfigs.unsigned*.

I'm not sure how to target a specific build variant (i.e., *amazonRelease*) so I can set its signingConfig.

This is what I currently have in my `build.gradle`:

```
android {

  ...

  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile ...;
      keyAlias ...;
      storePassword ...;
      keyPassword ...;
    }

    unsigned {
      keyAlias "";
      storePassword "";
      keyPassword "";
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      versionNameSuffix = "-DEBUG"
    }

    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release;
    }
  }

  flavorGroups "storeFront"

  productFlavors {
    google {
      flavorGroup "storeFront"
    }

    amazon {
      flavorGroup "storeFront"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to bother. Just submit your normal signed APK to Amazon, and they'll re-sign it with their own certificate. I submit the exact same APK to both Google Play and Amazon without any problems.

Comment: Graham is mostly right, you are still required to change the package name from the one you use on Google Play (even if that requirement is not strictly enforced by Amazon), but Amazon no longer requires you to submit an unsigned application: https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/submitting-your-app#Add%20Binary%20Files

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I wonder how I am currently able to submit the same APK to both stores? Do you know if it's a recent requirement to have a unique Amazon-specific package name?

Comment: @GrahamBorland, I have no idea. I just checked the Way Back Machine, but that particular documentation page is not even indexed by it. Obviously, if they already let you publish it under a particular package name, it would really be foolish and it would go against their own interests as an app store to force you to you change it retroactively.

Comment: The reason I believe I need an unsigned APK is to get facebook login into work. The double signing is preventing the login to work. If I upload a signed APK, then they don't supply me with the key hash (at least I can't find it) I need to enter in my Facebook app dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-Flavor-Configuration):

> There are cases where a setting is settable on both the Build Type and the Product Flavor. In this case, it’s is on a case by case basis.
>
> For instance, signingConfig is one of these properties.
>
> This enables either having all release packages share the same SigningConfig, by setting android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig, or have each release package use their own SigningConfig by setting each android.productFlavors.*.signingConfig objects separately.

So, I'd try removing the `release` `signingConfig` and adding `signingConfig` properties to `google` and `amazon`. If I understand the docs correctly, the `debug` `signingConfig` will trump the `google` and `amazon` `signingConfig` properties for debug builds, and release builds will use the ones defined on the flavors.

Comment: I added the following, but the GoogleRelease now throws two errors saying it can't find values `storePassword` and `keyPassword`: `productFlavors {
        google {
            flavorGroup "storeFront"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        amazon {
            flavorGroup "storeFront"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
        }
    }`

Comment: @HMCFletch: I can't really help you there, insofar as your code does not show what you are using for those, and I don't know the exact message (and trace info) you are getting from Gradle. Consider editing your question with an up-to-date redacted version of your `build.gradle` file, along with the exact output that you are getting.

Comment: I have traced it to some issues with using `System.getenv("RELEASE_PASSWORD")` instead of having the password literals in `build.gradle`. Your answer works with literals, so I'll go ahead and accept it. This seems to be a completely different issue. Thanks!